# getElementsById focus not working, next input

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code not working. I want use `getElementById` with focus, next input.

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="0" style="display: none; top: 359px; left: 432.5px; width: 239px;">
  <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-15" onclick="nextinput1()" tabindex="1">t1</li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-16" onclick="nextinput1()" tabindex="1">t2</li>
</ul>
<script>
  function nextinput1(){
    document.getElementById("kkInput").focus();
  }
</script>


<input id="kkInput" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" class="nextinput" " name="kkin" placeholder="" autocomplete="new-password" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)">
```

Comment: Try moving the script above the markup that is trying to use it as an inline binding

Comment: There is also a markup issue with a stray " in this part `class="nextinput" " name="kkin"`

Answer (score 0):

```
style="display: none;
```

You need to remove this style from the parent ul tag. Not sure why that's there.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to close the function, here is the correct code:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="0" style=" top: 359px; left: 432.5px; width: 239px;">
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-15" onclick="nextinput1()" tabindex="1">t1</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-16" onclick="nextinput1()" tabindex="1">t2</li></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function nextinput1(){
        document.getElementById("kkInput").focus();
     }
</script>

<input id="kkInput" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" class="nextinput" " name="kkin" placeholder="" autocomplete="new-password" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)">
```